# Check if pdf document is encrypted with Spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I would like to check if a pdf document is encrypted. We could use the `.is_encrypted` way from `pypdf` like this:

```
import pypdf

if pypdf.PdfReader("test_doc_encrypted.pdf").is_encrypted:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Output:

```
Yes
```

But I would like to only use `spacy` for this. So I was wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to check if a document is encrypted using `spacy`?

To make it reproducible, here I share the encrypted pdf document: [encrypted document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pstF7TxjvFW5mV264G6QW_53KGRIs2vO/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2.

PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

**Spacy is not a pdf parsing library.**

- If you want to check if a pdf is encrypted, use pypdf. Or if you want to manipulate pdf.
- If you want to do natural language processing (nlp) use Spacy.

Answer (score 0):

Spacy is a library made for text processing and provides little tools for document manipulation.
There is no direct way of checking whether a PDF file is encrypted using only spacy.

The best practices for checking the encryption for PDF files include `pypdf` or - even better - `pypdf2`.

Comment: Soon I will merge : https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/pull/1816